# VNC server, how to show upper right panel?

Tags: 16.04, vncviewer, tightvncserver

I installed TightVNC Server version 1.3.10 in ubuntu 16.04. The configuration in xstartup file is as following.

```
#!/bin/bash
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
gnome-panel &
metacity &
gnome-terminal &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid gray
vncconfig -iconic &
```

My problem is that the upper right panel showing username, clock, and other things does not appear.

[image]

How can I make it correct?

Comment: Can you manually add those indicators? To see if they can work in the first place. You can run them using the terminal, to see if there is an error somewhere.

Comment: @luchonacho, What command should I use to add them?

Comment: That is a good question. I am running Xfce (Xubuntu), and don't know much about Gnome. But test first the whole panel. Run `killall gnome-panel` to close it, and then, again from the terminal, run `gnome-panel`. See what happens.